# Save career posting for later and filter by experience required

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

As a person who scans over job postings somewhat regularly on SO Careers, there are two features I thought of that could help improve the process of searching for and applying for jobs.

The first one is the ability to bookmark a job to your profile for later. Sometimes I am browsing job postings on my iPhone, and do not really have a way to immediately find the job later in the day when I am back at my Windows desktop to apply (without writing down the exact job title to perform a search or something similar). I understand this is easily remedied by the method I just mentioned, but might be something nice to have.

The second feature is the ability to filter jobs by required years experience. I realize that you should not let the recommended or required years of experience on the job posting stop you from applying, because you never know what could happen, but for those of us just starting our careers and with less than a year or so under our belt, it seems pointless to have jobs in our list that require 5+ years of experience.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be pleased to hear that we more or less already have those features!

For the first one you can click the star to the left of the listing in the results view:

[image: Results: Favorites]

Or by clicking the 'Add to Favorites' button in the sidebar in the detail view:

[image: Detail: Favorites]

This will add the job to a list of favorites that you can retrieve by using the list of favorites in the results sidebar:

[image: My Favorites]

The second feature is more of a proxy for years of experience. We don't ask employers for this information because it generally isn't really helpful for filtering jobs. Instead we do ask for 'Seniority'. You can filter for this by performing an advanced search. E.g.

[Senior Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=seniority%3Asenior)
or
[Junior Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=seniority%3Ajunior)

You can see all the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/help).

Finally you can add seniority to your match preferences by clicking the cog in the 'matches' tab:

[image: Match Preferences]

And adding seniority:

[image: Updating Match Preferences]

Note: you need to be a registered user to use all this functionality.

Comment: That's great! I have been missing the add to favorites on the sidebar this whole time. I did know about the seniority filter. Sometimes the companies description of seniority doesn't quite match what I had in mind as far as experience required (ex. https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/105554/web-qa-developer-innovatix   - filtered as junior, requires 3+ years of experience)

Comment: Years experience is a difficult thing to quantify. For example, in the listing you mentioned, they have 3 sentences mentioning number of years experience. Which one would you expect to search on?